# Visual Studio 2013 displaying projects that don't exist in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have VS 2013 connected to my Visual Studio Online account and TFS.  I check-in my solution there everyday.

The problem is, if I create a project and realize I created the wrong type of project and remove it (and then delete it from the filesystem), when it comes time to check-in the project to TFS, it displays that removed project and all the files to check-in.

Then I need to select the ghost project and exclude it from the check-in.

Is this a known issue?  If so, how can I prevent VS from displaying these ghost projects?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @JohnSaunders - wow, what's happened to this world if you can't say "Hi", or "Thanks" in posts anymore.

Comment: Read the link I posted and you'll find that you are not meant to be having a conversation here on [so]. This is not another web forum.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I did read the post, but this is just me saying that it's not something I knew about and I'm not sure how those words constitute a conversation.  And I will obey this in the future, but I just wasn't aware that this was a policy. No offense.

Comment: No offense taken, and, "now you know that".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an issue as such but by design. If you're creating a project and ticking `Add to Source Control` it'll start tracking changes.

However, deleting the physical project won't stop TFS from tracking the changes because as far as it's concerned, the files still exist.

Before you remove any physical files, you need to undo pending changes, which includes the adding the project to source control, then you'll be able to safely delete the physical files.

Comment: I only clicked the "Add to Source Control" for the original projects, not for new projects I've added. Ok, I understand now how to delete projects in the future, but how do I delete those ghost projects already in source control?